# SUMIF#N/A with Subtotal

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a question on the formula that I have been trying to combine below formula and did not success.

```
=SUMIF(A2:A9,"<>#N/A",A2:A9)
=SUBTOTAL(9,A2:A9)
```

[image]

Comment: What is your exact issue? Do you get wrong result? Error message? maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: Subtotal function 9 is a normal Sum (cannot avoid #N/A) but Sumif sum only the numbers <> #N/A

Comment: If you use "#N/A" (write the quotes) subtotal will sum the numbers and ignore the cells with error

Comment: You can hide the error if you are using Filter and use Subtotal (it will ignore hidden rows)

Comment: If you have the function Aggregate write this formula: `=aggregate(9,3,A2:A9)`  it will ignore errors, hidden rows and aggregates

Answer (score 0):

Use your filter to hide rows under Amount that have the value #N/A (error) and write the same formula for Subtotal it will give you the same result as Sumif

[image]

Also you can write "#N/A" (add quotes) Subtotal will understand it as text and ignore it
Usually Sum and Subtotal cannot ignore error and it result with error but it ignore text
If your Excel has the function Aggregate you can use it, Aggregate with special argument ignore error, hidden rows...
`=aggregate(9,3,A2:A9)`
9 for Sum
3 to ignore error, hidden rows and other aggregates
For more information on using Subtotal to sum visible rows click on 
https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-visible-rows-in-a-filtered-list

Comment: Thank you so much. It works with your formula of aggregate.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if you are satisfied